# Rust get executable path of process by window handle or process id

Tags: windows, rust, process, windows-rs, getmodulefilename

I'm trying to get executable path of process on `Windows` OS. I have window handle coming from some windows event, from window handle I can acquire process id using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`. Then, according to [windows api docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexa) I can use `OpenProcess()` function to make process handle and then with this use `GetModuleFileNameExA()` or `GetModuleFileNameExW()` for unicode characters to get process executable path. But sadly, in `windows` crate I can't find none of this functions.

I tried to use `GetWindowModuleFileNameW()`, but this works only for process that is calling this function or processes that come from this process (that's might be not exact explanation, but the way I understand it).

I found this functions in `winapi` crate, but as I was suggested earlier, I better use `windows` crate because its still maintained unlike `winapi`.

Also I found kind of way to do this with `sysinfo` crate, but if possible, I would like to not bring it just for this.
Any help will be appreciated!

UPD: There is `OpenProcess()` function available after I installed rest of `windows` crate features, but this still can't help me much without `GetModuleFileNameExW()`

UPDD: I found feature in `windows` crate called `Win32_System_ProcessStatus` which contains necessary functions. My problem is solved and I leave this here in case anybody will have same question.

Comment: The documentation of the `windows-rs` crate lists the required features for every API call. In case of [`GetModuleFileNameExW`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/ProcessStatus/fn.GetModuleFileNameExW.html) it has the following: *"Required features: "Win32_System_ProcessStatus", "Win32_Foundation""*.

Comment: Yes, thank you, thats exactly how I found this. I thought that all features were listed in their github example, which is not true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`windows`](https://crates.io/crates/windows) crate, like the API it provides bindings for, is massive. It comprises quite literally hundreds of thousands of line of code. To tame compile times, the crate is split into modules, each gated behind a feature.

To use any given API binding, client code needs to enable the respective feature(s). The [documentation](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/) lists the required feature(s) for every public constant, type, or function.

[`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/UI/WindowsAndMessaging/fn.GetWindowThreadProcessId.html):

> *Required features: `"Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging"`, `"Win32_Foundation"`*

[`OpenProcess`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/Threading/fn.OpenProcess.html):

> *Required features: `"Win32_System_Threading"`, `"Win32_Foundation"`*

[`GetModuleFileNameExW`](https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/System/ProcessStatus/fn.GetModuleFileNameExW.html):

> *Required features: `"Win32_System_ProcessStatus"`, `"Win32_Foundation"`*

To implement this program, the *Cargo.toml* file must contain the following table:

```ini
[dependencies.windows]
version = "0.48.0"    # Current version as of writing
features = [
    "Win32_Foundation",
    "Win32_System_ProcessStatus",
    "Win32_System_Threading",
    "Win32_UI_WindowsAndMessaging",
]
```